# template class declaration - is not a constant expression

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

I have the following class which I need to have two constants upon declaration.

```
template <int PAGE_DIV_SIZE, int BUFFERS_NUM>
    class BufferPool {
    //...
    }
```

And 
here is a test code for its use

```
void testBufferPool(const int pageDivSize, const int bufferNum){   

    // other code and declaration

    BufferPool <pageDivSize, bufferNum> bufferPool(catalog, devNum, hostCapacityVec, devCapacityVec);


}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: ‘pageDivSize’ is not a constant expression
BufferPoolTest.cpp:26:39: note: in template argument for type ‘int’ 
BufferPoolTest.cpp:26:39: error: ‘bufferNum’ is not a constant expression
BufferPoolTest.cpp:26:39: note: in template argument for type ‘int’ 
BufferPoolTest.cpp:26:51: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘(’ token
BufferPoolTest.cpp:26:100: error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]
BufferPoolTest.cpp:26:100: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<long unsigned int>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to instantiate template, compiler must know all template arguments at compile time. There is no way to figure out the values of pageDivSize and bufferNum at compile time. So template argument should not be a constant variable, but a constant expression.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression